# how do i write my function so that when entered it will print the delimeter is too long?

Tags: python, string, split, function

I was having trouble on how to write out my function, so that when more than one character is entered, it prints out the statement that the delimeter is too long. and returns the value none.But I don't know how to do it. New to python and it would be a great help with some information. thanks in advance
this what I have done.

```
def my_split(_,_):
    my_sep = input("seperator: ")
    my_str = input("sentence: ")



def main():
    #your main program here
    print("Enter a string to be split: ")
    print("Enter the delimiter character: ") 
    print("the result is: ")


for(my_sep):
    if(my_sep <1):
    print(" the delimeter is too long.")

return None

print("enter a string to be split: ")
print("enter the delimeter character: ")
print(" the result is: ")



main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if len(my_sep) > 1:
    print(" the delimiter is too long")
    return None
```

But it's not clear where you want to put this in your code. What function are you trying to return `None` from? I think you want something like this:

```
def main():
    #your main program here
    my_str = input("Enter a string to be split: ")
    my_sep = input("Enter the delimiter character: ") 
    if len(my_sep) > 1:
        print(" the delimeter is too long.")
        return None
    result = # do the actual splitting code here
    return result

result = main()
print("the result is:", result)
```

Having filled in the `# do the actual splitting code here`, here's what happens when I run this twice:

```
Enter a string to be split: Hello, World
Enter the delimiter character: ,
 the result is: ['Hello', ' World']

Enter a string to be split: Hello, World
Enter the delimiter character: lo
 the delimiter is too long.
 the result is: None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_split(_,_):
    my_sep = input("seperator: ")
    my_str = input("sentence: ")
```

Here you are defining a function called "my_split".  You are telling Python that "my_split" takes two parameters, but you are giving both of those parameters the name "_" (underscore).  This is not valid.  Since it looks like this function doesn't need any input from the program, and instead takes input from the user, you can declare the function without any parameters:

```
def my_split():
    my_sep = raw_input("seperator: ")
    my_str = raw_input("sentence: ")
    return my_sep,my_str
```

Notice I've also changed from input() to raw_input().  input() is a function that executes code input from the terminal.  This is not what you want to do.  You also need to return the values you've collected.

```
def main():
    #your main program here
    print("Enter a string to be split: ")
    print("Enter the delimiter character: ") 
    print("the result is: ")
```

There's nothing technically wrong with your main() function, but it doesn't do what you want it to do.  It prints those three lines and ends.  Here's a more complete main() that takes advantage of the my_split function we've already written:

```
def main():
    my_sep,my_str = my_split()
    result = my_str.split(my_sep)
    print "the result is: ", result
```

Notice you can return two values from a function, and set two values with the call to that function.

```
for(my_sep):
    if(my_sep <1):
    print(" the delimeter is too long.")
```

The first line here is not valid python.  `for` is a loop structure, meant to loop through each element of a group.  Also, you wanted to know if the length is too long, but your condition is "less than one".  Thirdly, your print call should be indented to indicate it is part of the "if" statement's body.  And lastly, this should all be inside the main() function.  So, a final program would look like this:

```
def my_split():
    my_sep = raw_input("seperator: ")
    my_str = raw_input("sentence: ")
    return my_sep,my_str

def main():
    my_sep,my_str = my_split()
    if len(my_sep) > 1:
        print " the delimeter is too long."
    else:
        result = my_str.split(my_sep)
        print "the result is: ", result


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You almost definitely do not want to change from `input` to `raw_input`, since the OP is probably working in Python 3 (given the `print` functions rather than `print` statements).